# Changing IP address using .net core on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, network-programming, ip-address, system.net

Is there a way to use .net core code to change networking configuration (IP address, mask, default gateway, DNS, DHCP)
On a Linux operating system? (I am using Ubuntu 18.4.2 LTS )

I can use for some extent the following libraries:

```
System.Net
System.Net.NetworkInformation
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net?view=netcore-2.2

using them I can get the networking information (the IP and the gateway are retrieved properly, the DNS information is always "127.0.0.53",  and the DHCP information not supported on Linux),
but I can't find in the .net documentation how to set/change the networking configuration like IP address, gateway, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know, there is no built-in way to do this with .NET Core framework. And IMHO there will never be.

But of course, you can do it with invoking system commands.
You can use [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netcore-2.2) and then call these (and any other) commands.

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.66.6 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
...
```

Of course, your process must run as superuser.